# Creating PEM, pfx,... from private modulus,

Tags: openssl, rsa, pki, pem, pfx

i received the following from some legacy system when i asked for private key: 
MODULUS, PUBLIC  EXP, PRIVATE EXP, PRIME_P, PRIME_Q, PARAM_P, PARAM_Q, Q_MOD_INV

All of this data is in hex, how can i convert this to a openssl PEM file or PFX ?

Thank you and best regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate RSA key with openssl:

```
openssl genrsa -out rsa.pem 2048
```

Convert RSA key from PEM format to DER format:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -in rsa.pem -outform DER -out rsa.der
```

Open file rsa.der in [ASN.1 Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4910/ASN-1-Editor):

[image: File rsa.der opened in ASN.1 Editor]

ASN.1 structure of RSA private key is defined in PKCS#1 (RFC 3447):

```
  RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
      version           Version,
      modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
      publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
      privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
      prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
      prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
      exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
      exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
      coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
      otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
  }
```

Edit required fields in ASN.1 Editor (right click the item and choose "Edit in hex mode") and paste your data following this mapping:

```
  MODULUS = modulus
  PUBLIC EXP = publicExponent
  PRIVATE EXP = privateExponent
  PRIME_P = prime1
  PRIME_Q = prime2
  PARAM_P = exponent1
  PARAM_Q = exponent2
  Q_MOD_INV = coefficient
```

**Edit based on the comments:** Individual parts of the private key are big integers. When the leftmost bit of the value is 1 (or leftmost byte equals or is bigger than 0x80) then 0x00 byte needs to be preppended to the value to indicate it is positive number.

Finally save the modified file and convert it from DER format to PEM format with openssl:

```
openssl rsa -inform DER -in rsa.der -outform PEM -out rsa.pem
```

Comment: When i open the generated der file modulus is 257 length and private exp also 257... I have 256 bytes of data and now when i edited and converted to pem and trying to see the details of the cert i get:
unable to load certificate
3068241860:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Comment: Individual parts of the private key are big integers. When the leftmost bit of the value is 1 (or leftmost byte is bigger than 0x80) then 0x00 byte is usually preppended to the value to indicate it is positive number. That is probably the reason why you have 257 bytes in one key and 256 bytes in the other key. You can preppend 0x00 to the values that meet this condition in your private key.

Comment: Certificate parsing error indicates that your certificate file is probably not stored in the correct PEM encoding. You can try to parse it as a DER encoded certificate using "openssl x509 -inform DER -in file.cer -text" command. If that won't work open the certificate file in text editor and describe its contents in the comment (i.e. it is binary file, hex encoded - contains only numbers, base64 encoded - contains both numbers and printable characters etc.).

Comment: I have corrected the 0x00 to meet the positive/negative and still the same! When i textout DER i get: ~ # openssl x509 -inform DER -in rsa.der -text
unable to load certificate
3068241860:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1329:
3068241860:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:381:Type=X509_CINF
3068241860:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:761:Field=cert_info, Type=X509

Comment: This is strange: root@ubuntu:/home/user# openssl genrsa -out rsa.pem 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
..................+++
...........................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
root@ubuntu:/home/user# openssl x509 -in rsa.pem -text
unable to load certificate
3074160840:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICAT

Comment: I thin i figured it out, this a rsa key not a cert, so no info can be displayed! The procedure in the answer WORKS with the addition of @jariq comment!

Comment: That is correct. This file stores just RSA key. I have edited my answer and added info about big integers.